# Nant foreach include exclude filter not working as expected

Tags: nant

I wish to exclude particular files from a nant (0.91) target and process the remainder.
Here's the code snippet, which shows I want to include all .js files but exclude foo.
foo is not being excluded.  I've tried putting the exclude before the include but same result.

```xml
<foreach item="File" in="${built.web.directory}\Content\js" property="filename">
  <in>
    <items basedir="${built.web.directory}\Content\js">
      <include name="/**/*.js" />
      <exclude name="**/foo.1.2.js" />
    </items>
  </in>
  <do>
    <echo message="Compressing ${filename}" />
    <exec
      program="${packer.exe}"
      commandline="-o ${built.web.directory}\Content\js\${path::get-file-name(filename)} -m jsmin ${filename}"
    />
  </do>
</foreach>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have specified the *in* attribute on *foreach* which is overriding the *items* element. Try changing:

```
<foreach item="File" in="${built.web.directory}\Content\js" property="filename">
```

to:

```
<foreach item="File" property="filename">
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```xml
<fileset id="javascript.files" basedir="${built.web.directory}\Content\js">
  <include name="/**/*.js" />
  <exclude name="**/foo.1.2.js" />
  <exclude name="**/*.min.js" />
</fileset>

<foreach item="File" property="filename">
  <in>
    <items refid="javascript.files" />
  </in>
  <do>
    <echo message="Compressing ${filename}" />
    <exec
      program="${packer.exe}"
      commandline="-o ${built.web.directory}\Content\js\${path::get-file-name(filename)} -m jsmin ${filename}"
    />
  </do>
</foreach>
```

Comment: This was all I wanted: . . . ${path::get-file-name(filename)}  . . .  thanks